# Hyperledger fabric wont create channel in test environment when following the steps

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am getting this error when running test-network % ./network.sh createChannel -c channel1

2022-09-21 08:35:22.905 EDT [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> WARN 006 Genesis block does not contain a consortiums group definition.  This block cannot be used for orderer bootstrap.

then it fails. I am just trying this out and I am new to deploying hyperledger so not sure what a fix would be. This is a test environment using docker.

Comment: Seems like you missed to add consortium details in configtx.yaml. Can you share configtx.yaml contents?

Comment: I tried to but it seems like it is too long. I took some screenshots. Is there a way to add consortium details or do you know what it would look like in config tx if it is there?

Comment: I ended up just removing the images on docker and adding them back again and it fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

I see that you managed to make it work by manually removing the running container. If you are running network.sh, then always use "down" option to cleanup. Refer to the link [Bring up the test network](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/test_network.html#bring-up-the-test-network).

Once you are familiar with the script and network, and if you want to retain the data, (If you are still using network.sh to bring down the network,) perhaps you could remove the down --volumes --remove-orphans from the networkDown() function call to docker-compose.

```
sh network.sh down
```

or

```
./network.sh down
```